# remix data getting lost

Tags: remix

when i try to code in remix either in online or desktop mode,when I have created a workspace and  have done some work in it from checking what the funtions like uint view, then after some days  there is no work record showing. I  have faced this problems sevral time, in desktop mode the workspace is present but my work that will be the file is not, idk what to do?

i thought that in online mode it is happening because the cache is not saving in system but the problem still exists in desktop app as well.

Comment: It is quite strange. I've been using remix online for several years an still have very old contracts available. I've used it with firefox, chrome, brave no issue with any of them. I'd suggest to check if you have some incompatibility with another plugin. It is really odd that it also happens with the desktop version. I'd check if there's a malware in your system.

Comment: well im using it with brave and have recently baught a new laptop so i dont think that there will any malware but i will still check it . 
I want to know one thing that if I clear cache in my computer will it delete all the files of online as well as desktop ide ?

Comment: The online version stores the contracts locally, so if you clear the browser local storage you are deleting remix contracts. If you have to do that I'd suggest to download a backup copy before doing so.

Comment: what about the desktop version it is also not showing my work

Comment: Sorry, I haven't used the desktop version.

Answer (score 1):

So apparently the problem was arising because I was removing the cache from the system, for both the desktop and browser versions, and once I stopped doing that the data was not getting lost.

Answer (score 1):

This happens for me often too and I have played around with solutions.

1.) Use the features that remix offers. When you create a project, you should see a check-button asking you if you'd like to create the file as a git project. Then you could save it via git.

2.) After you are done with your coding session, save your code in an external file on your computer.